# Net user command incorrectly displays password expiration date; script that reads field and outputs if expired is incorrect. Possible workaround?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory

Ok, so here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

powershell "$uid=(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter UserID');$u = (net user $uid /domain);$u;$lockout=($u | select-string -pattern 'Account active.*Locked');$expired=((get-date ([String]($u | select-string 'Password expires')).Substring(16).Trim()) -lt (get-date));if ($lockout) { Write-Host 'Account locked out' -Foreground 'Red' } else { Write-Host 'Account not locked out' -Foreground 'Green' } if ($expired) { Write-Host 'Password Expired' -Foreground 'Red' } else { Write-Host 'Password not expired' -foreground 'Green' }"

pause
```

[image: Here is what the output looks like]

A little background if you'd like it, otherwise skip down a little.

*I'm a level 1 service desk analyst, my users will call in saying they think their password is expired or account is locked. I've been doing this a while so it isn't an issue for me to look up their account in active directory. I'm part of what is a dedicated team, meaning we serve only 1 client. We have what is called leverage teams that take calls when dedicated is busy. I'm making this to help the leverage guys have an easier time as they don't always have the AD resource loaded.*

**Skip to here if you don't care about back story:**

The issue I'm running into, is our active directory incorrectly displays the password expiration date when performing "net user %username% /domain". It shows as 1 year from the password last set field when it should be 90 days from the last set date. Making the part of my batch file that outputs if it is expired always incorrect.

Can I grab the password last set field, add 90 days, and have it output the date the password expires? Or compare that date to the current date, and determine if it has passed already? Maybe subtract a year and add 90 days to the password expiration date field? This is all very foreign to me as I have pieced most of it together from google searches, this site, reddit, and some colleagues here at work. So I'm open to suggestions.

**I great appreciate any assistance you can provide, and if this is the wrong location for this, my apologies.**

Edit1: So I tried something and changed a line;

I changed:

```
$expired=((get-date ([String]($u | select-string 'Password expires')).Substring(16).Trim()) -lt (get-date))
```

to

```
$expired=((get-date ([String]($u | select-string 'Password last set')).Substring(16).Trim()) -lt (get-date).AddDays(30))
```

but now I get an error.

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "t            10/18/2018 8:13:05 AM" to type
"System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at
index 0."
At line:1 char:156
+ ... =((get-date ([String]($u | select-string 'Password last set')).Substr ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

**This is what I ended up with and it works perfectly in the environment I need it.**

```
@echo off
powershell "$uid=(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter UserID');$u = (net user $uid /domain);$u;$lockout=($u | select-string -pattern 'Account active.*Locked');$expiredate=get-date ([String]($u | select-string 'Password expires')).Substring(16).Trim();$expired=$expiredate.AddDays(-275) -lt (get-date);if ($lockout) { Write-Host 'Account locked out' -Foreground 'Red' } else { Write-Host 'Account not locked out' -Foreground 'Green' } if ($expired) { Write-Host 'Password Expired' -Foreground 'Red' } else { Write-Host 'Password not expired' -foreground 'Green' }"
pause
```

Comment: You need to talk to your AD admin to figure out what the root cause is if you think the password is supposed to expire in 90 days. You sure there isn't a policy in place for that user that allows them that year?

Comment: Are you sure they expire in 90 days? You can use `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` in PowerShell to check the "MaxPasswordAge" policy on your domain. For example, ours is "30.00:00:00", which means 30 days.

Comment: Or in AD Users and Computers, in the Attribute Editor tab for the user, look at the `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` attribute (make sure you have 'Constructed' attributes enabled from the 'Filter' button menu). See if it tells you something different.

Comment: I do know for certain our policy has passwords expire after 90 days of being set, contacting the AD admin to have this correct is unfortunately not an option as they will simply tell me, "add 90 days to the last set date and figure it out". :/ I tried something, hopefully its getting me to the right location.

Comment: I would push back if this is a common problem.  This is an AD problem. Not your problem.  I was lucky enough to get along with all the head admins when I worked in Networking. If I didn't know how to do something I asked and they showed me how to fix it.

Comment: Don't you think it would be a lot easier to code the whole thing properly as a powershell script instead of trying to slam it all onto one a one liner?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to really push back on this. My company contracts out my services to another, so I work in their environment remotely from my companies, I have little interaction/contact with admins as I just troubleshoot and escalate tickets when I cannot resolve. As for making this into a powershell script, I honestly have no idea where to begin with that as this was partially passed down from a previous employee with a few minor adjustments by myself from google searches. I guess I could just search how to do it in there and see if I can achieve the same result.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if `net user` is giving you wrong results. Does `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` actually tell you that the "MaxPasswordAge" is "90.00:00.00"?

Comment: I appreciate the concern Gabriel. I can say with certainty that our password policy is 90 days for the environment in question as this was information provided to be and I've observed it first hand. I could not get `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` to run in powershell or CMD so not exactly sure where to type it.

Comment: That's for PowerShell, but maybe you don't have the ActiveDirectory module installed. You can also check it by opening AD Users and Computers, right click on the root of the domain -> Properties -> Attribute Editor tab, and check the value of `maxPwdAge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the password expiration for a user, you can convert the attribute `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` to `DateTime`

Below I put together an example to go into more details. The variable names should be self-explanatory to what they are. If you run the example, you will notice that the attribute `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` should give you the expired date needed. However, the other options (adding 90 days) are included in the example.

Example (**updated**):

```
    [string]$Identity = "User Account"     
    $expiredDate = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($((Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity -Properties 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed').'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed'))
    $lastSetDate = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($((Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity -Properties 'pwdLastSet').'pwdLastSet'))
    Write-Host "Exipred Date: " $expiredDate
    Write-Host "Last Set Date: " $lastSetDate 

    $lastDate_Plus90 = $lastSetDate.AddDays(90)

    Write-Host "Last Set + 90 days: " $lastDate_Plus90
```

Comment: Could I use this to pull the password last set date and then add 90 days?

Comment: @MackenzieWilliams I have updated the solution to go into further detail

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much. Haven't got it to work with what I have fully but I believe this is what I was missing. :D Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @MackenzieWilliams Glad to help. If this solved your issue, please mark it as the answer

Comment: Will do! I am going to wait until I can get it working with the rest of what I have so I can post the outcome, if that's acceptable at least.

Comment: @MackenzieWilliams sounds good. Let me know if you have any additional issues.

Comment: This is what I ended up with and it works perfectly in the environment I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, You could try some LDAP search.

```
$Searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.Filter="(&(samaccountname=username))"
$Results=$Searcher.findone()
$Results.Properties
```

will give you a lot of information and password last set is one among them.

I would suggest you to give the support team a PowerShell script instead of a batch file.

Comment: `net user` is just pulling that same data.

Comment: I appreciate the information, as this would require I completely rewrite what I have and I already invested a lot of time into it, I'll keep this open as a backup option to search into further.

Comment: You can also shorten this: `$s = [adsisearcher]'(&(samaccountname=username))'`